# long running tasks under asmx service hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asmx

I have some legacy ASMX IIS hosted service. Client applications make subscribe or unsubscribe to the web service. Via some internal to the web service logic it needs to send messages to the subscribed applications periodically.

What is the best way to do the part of the long running task ? I understand opening Thread with long running task not a good idea to do under IIS.

Comment: why opening Thread with long running task is not good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASMX services cannot do what you're asking for: they cannot just decide to send a message to the client. All they can do is respond if the client requests it.

You can hack around and come up with one method to start the long-running task, and another method to poll for the status of the task. This works, but it can be expensive.

The better model is to perform the long-running task in a separate Windows Service. Have that service host a simple WCF service which will only be used by the main service (the one that talks to the clients). The main (WCF) service would use a Duplex channel to communicate with the clients. That way, it can "call" the clients whenever there is news about one of the long-running tasks.

Comment: +1 It should be noted that "under the hood" the duplex channel works basically the same way (polling), but it is "wrapped" nicely to give a different feel.

Comment: @Hogan: I didn't know that. In that case, I'll add, "Don't reinvent the wheel".

Comment: Doesn't it have to be?  A server can't "call" a browser, browsers can only request.  Of course, I'm assuming the user is using web based applications -- a server side application could communicate directly using WCF or any protocol.

Comment: I was talking about a Duplex channel between the web service that the browsers talk to and the Windows Service which is running the long-running tasks. The tasks can be running in the Windows service, perhaps with code to resume them in case of failure. The web clients can ask the "front-end" web service for the status of the long-running tasks. That "front-end" service can use the duplex connection the the Windows service to be notified, so it doesn't have to poll the windows service.

Comment: Got it, ignore my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such cases when you don't have a way to push the result back, create an unique ID for the long running task and sent it back to the client, after that run the task and have a table in database or something else where you store the status of the task. The client will pull periodically the service to see the task' status by given ID. Once it finds the task is completed it will retrieve the result. 
And is completely fine to have a thread running inside IIS doing its job.